# Exchange ResolveNames call replace with Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Microsoft forces users to switch from EWS to Graph for office online because they will drop support from october 2020 (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/exchange-team-blog/upcoming-changes-to-exchange-web-services-ews-api-for-office-365/ba-p/608055) so I'm working on move from EWS to Graph.

There is a call in EWS(Exchange Web services) for resolving names 'ResolvedNames' - "The ResolveNames operation resolves ambiguous email addresses and display names." [microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/resolvenames-operation)

Active Directory is searched first, and then the user's contact folder is searched. With the help of this resolve call - you can find primary email address and also resolve names such as "/o=ExchangeLabs...".

In clean configuration of just office 365 - users will not have x500 records in the proxyAddresses collection of User resource. So there is no way to resolve "/o=ExchangeLabs"-like address in this case ?

So what is the equivalent of ResolveNames(EWS) in Graph ? For now I just do the search against proxyAddresses for User resource, but maybe there is exists(or planned) some other way to do resolve?

Comment: Hi Dmytro, did you find something? or you still using proxyAddresses

Comment: @NitinChopra still using proxyAddresses. With Azure sync it's possible to automate x500 sync. I dont like it, but there is no resolve via graph as I know.

Comment: Thanks Dmytro, Will see if i can use azure sync works and will try to make it work in POC.